# Clickable link into checkbox label

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I used Bootstrap for making this form and adding a checkbox for the privacy.
But my link is not clickable:

```
<div class="row">
  <div style="margin: auto; margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 12px; text-align: justify;">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col-lg">
      <input name="privacy" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="privacy" required>
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="privacy">
        I have read the <span><a class="privacy" href="https://www.example.com">privacy policy</a></span>
        and consent to the storage of my data in your archive as
        established by the European regulation for the protection of personal data n. 679/2016,
        GDPR.
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post all your code in html file?

Comment: The link is working normally for me, its clickable. It will be better if you share every code you have.

Comment: @adcoding: It's working for me as well. https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ebfm2L05/2/